# String is not passing through constructor argument

Tags: c++, string, arguments

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>

class student{
    int roll_no;
    char name[15];
    float per;
public:
    student(int a, char b[15], float c){
        roll_no = a;
        name[15] = b[15];
        per = c;
    }
    ~student(void){
        cout << "Student Details : \n\n"
             << "Roll No : " << roll_no << "\n"
             << "Name : " << name[15] << "\n"
             << "Percentage : " << per << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    student s(60,"Suraj Jadhav",25.25);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Output is : 
    Student Details:

```
Roll No : 60
Name : 
Percentage : 25.25
```

Name is not displaying string..
Not sure what is the problem but want to solve.. Please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when you declare

```
char name[15];
```

name is an array of 15 char. The parameter b is a pointer ("expected" to point to an array of 15 chars). The statement

```
name[15] = b[15];
```

copy only the 16th element of the array pointed by "b" to the 16th element in the array "name" (count starts at zero), since there is 15 elements in the array there is no defined behavior here (the same way when you print name[15]).

In C you have to copy each character one after the other. Functions like strcpy takes care of that for you, it might be unsafe if destination is not large enough to accommodate source.
In C++ you should try to avoid using array of char and use std::string instead take will take of copy safely.
You should also use initializer list (the syntax to initialize member in the constructor). For instance:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include<conio.h>

class student{
    int roll_no;
    string name;
    float per;
public:
    student(int a, const string &b, float c) 
         : roll_no(a), name(b), per(c)
    {
    }
    ~student(){
        cout << "Student Details : \n\n"
             << "Roll No : " << roll_no << "\n"
             << "Name : " << name << "\n"
             << "Percentage : " << per << endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    student s(60,"Suraj Jadhav",25.25);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Note: `#include <conio.h>` is not standard C/C++, it is a specific MS-DOS header. Try to avoid if possible :)

Comment: This should be a comment. It doesn't answer the question (whatever it may be).

Comment: @0x499602D2 "The problem is caused by using C-style strings when you don't understand how they work. Use C++-style strings instead and you won't have this problem." is a valid answer, IMO, unless/until the OP clarifies that character arrays are required for some reason. That is roughly what's in this answer.

Comment: The way you formed the answer does not actually answer the question. If you're trying to make a suggestion, you need to post it as a *comment*.

Comment: @0x499602D2, you're right I updated (and I didn't author the previous comment). And BTW "You must have 50 reputation to comment" leaves me no choice :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Right, sorry for the confusion, I'm not Joky, I just commented because I thought it was already a valid answer before the edit. A better one after it, though. :)

Comment: Um: "*when you declare `char name[15];` name is a pointer to an array of 15 char.*" An array is an array, a pointer is a pointer. Don't mix the two :/

Comment: The first sentence is wrong; `name` is _not_ a pointer, but an array of 15 `char`.  (On the other hand, his `b` constructor parameter is a pointer.)

Comment: On the other hand, of course, `char name[15]` is _not_ the way you declare a string in C++.  Your final example is the only correct way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

```
name[15] = b[15];
```

won't copy the string. It'll just copy *one* character from `b` to `name`, specifically the one at index 15. (In fact, this is actually undefined behaviour, since each array only has indices 0..14.) Try this:

```
strcpy(name, b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use raw pointers if you do not understand them, use std::string instead. Anyway your constructor can be fixed like this:

```
student(int a, const char *b, float c){
    roll_no = a;
    strncpy( name, b, sizeof( name ) );
    per = c;
}
```

There is issue with `strncpy()` when string length (what `strlen()` returns and excluding \0 terminator) where b points to is equal or longer than size of `name` - it will not put \0 terminator into target string. So code could be safer this way:

```
student(int a, const char *b, float c){
    roll_no = a;
    name[ sizeof( name ) - 1 ] = 0;
    strncpy( name, b, sizeof( name ) - 1 );
    per = c;
}
```

Again working with raw pointers is pretty complex and you need to deeply understand what is going on there to write safe code. Using std::string in C++ will make your life much simpler.

Comment: You may want to consider what this does to `name` when `b[]` is *longer* than `sizeof(name)`-chars including its nulchar terminator. I'll save you the suspense; it doesn't terminate `name[]`. Any future string-scanning library functions (like `strcpy`, `strlen`, `strcmp`, etc.) that use it will invoke undefined-behavior searching for said-terminator.

Comment: @WhozCraig thanks, added safer variant, I think there should be another variant of strncpy that always puts terminator into target.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of invalid statement

```
name[15] = b[15];
```

you shall use C standard function `strcpy`that is declared in header

```
std::strcpy( name, b );
```

Also the correct declaration of the constructor will look the following way

```
student(int a, const char b[15], float c);
```

or

```
student(int a, const char b[], float c);
```

or

```
student(int a, const char *b, float c);
```

These three declarations declare the same function.

To make the constructor safe I would define it as

```
student(int a, const char b[], float c){
        roll_no = a;
        std::strncpy( name, b, 15 );
        name[14] = '\0';
        per = c;
}
```

Also it is a good idea to assign a name to the magic number 15 either using an enumerator or static constant.